# Running function using <SID> on commandline not working

Tags: vimscript

So i found the following vimscript [code](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5170):

```
let s:mappings = {
        \ 'k': {id -> s:scroll_line(id, -1)},
        \ 'j': {id -> s:scroll_line(id, 1)},
        \ 'd': {id -> s:scroll_page(id, 0.5)},
        \ 'u': {id -> s:scroll_page(id, -0.5)},
        \ 'f': {id -> s:scroll_page(id, 1)},
        \ 'b': {id -> s:scroll_page(id, -1)},
        \ 'g': {id -> popup_setoptions(id, #{firstline: 1})},
        \ 'G': {id -> s:bottom(id)},
        \ 'q': {id -> popup_close(id)}
        \ }

function! s:scroll_line(winid, step) abort
    let line = popup_getoptions(a:winid).firstline
    if a:step < 0
        let newline = (line + a:step) > 0 ? (line + a:step) : 1
    else
        let nlines = line('$', a:winid)
        let newline = (line + a:step) <= nlines ? (line + a:step) : nlines
    endif
    call popup_setoptions(a:winid, #{firstline: newline})
endfunction

function! s:scroll_page(winid, size) abort
    let height = popup_getpos(a:winid).core_height
    let step = float2nr(height*a:size)
    call s:scroll_line(a:winid, step)
endfunction

function! s:bottom(winid) abort
    let height = popup_getpos(a:winid).core_height
    let nlines = line('$', a:winid)
    let newline = (nlines - height) >= 0 ? (nlines - height + 1) : 1
    call popup_setoptions(a:winid, #{firstline: newline})
endfunction

function! s:popup_filter(winid, key) abort
    if has_key(s:mappings, a:key)
        call get(s:mappings, a:key)(a:winid)
        return v:true
    endif
    return v:false
endfunction

let text = range(50)->map({_,i -> string(i)})
call popup_create(text, #{
        \ minwidth: 40,
        \ maxwidth: 40,
        \ minheight: 8,
        \ maxheight: 8,
        \ firstline: 1,
        \ scrollbar: 1,
        \ mapping: v:false,
        \ filter: funcref('s:popup_filter')
        \ })
```

which run successfully if i run it with `vim --clean popup.vim -c "source %"` when put inside a file called `popup.vim` but fail if run by yanking and doing `@"`, with the following error `E120: Using <SID> not in a script context: s:scroll_line`.

I basically want to run it in the commandline, so i can do faster testing when adding/removing code, instead of saving/opening the file it reside at...(eg: fast prototyping etc)

How can i run this snippet on the Vim commandline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Use `:source %` instead.

Local functions and variables are indeed a limitation of the `:@` approach. As I actually mentioned in my answer to [your previous question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/27279/18609):

> There are some limitations, such as you can't define local functions and variables (in the `s:` namespace.)

If you want to be able to only load parts of it using the `:@` command, then you should turn the functions into global functions (without the `s:`, and starting with an uppercase letter), or perhaps using a namespace autoload-style function name will work (as in `mylinenumbers#scroll_page`, etc.) In either case, you'll have to go through all the call sites for every function to adapt them to the new style, which is not great...

Since you're editing them from a `*.vim` file, though, perhaps the best approach is to reload it using `:source %` every time you want to reload it. I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work, in fact I'd say that's probably the easiest approach of all.

Comment: Or `:Runtime`, if you use tpope/scriptease.

Comment: Using `:source %` was fine until i noticed you had to save first for it to work :/. At least i can make a mapping out of it that save first, and using tpope's scriptease work great too, as an alternative.

Comment: Actually it seems like `:Runtime` need the file to be saved first (afaik). Guess I'll post something related to that. :D